# Settings bundle - how to remove it

Tags: ios, iphone, settings.bundle

I've added settings bundle at the beginning of project then I've decided to have in-app settings which I've implemented. I've removed settings bundle but still settings are visible out of the app. How can it be? I've checked the Copy bundle resources and there is no trace of it.

Comment: Clean, Clean Build Folder and Build.

Comment: Clean - fine, but how to do Clean Build Folder?

Comment: Press alt and then clean

Comment: Please put those instructions in the answer, I will hapilly accept it. It will definitely help other noobs like me:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the build process is optimized for speed, some file will be kept in a build folder and copied to your app when you hit run. Thus removing them from your project will not always have the effect you want.

To solve this press <kbd>alt</kbd>+clean (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>) to clean the build folder, also notice that the name of clean command changes to `Clean Build Folder`.